# sax parser Exception (java and netbeans)

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, sax

im using sax parser to parse an xml file 
this is my xml file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LKUV.png)

and when i run my program i get this Exception or this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNKWJ.png)

i tryed to make some changes in my xml files such as deleting some tags but still get this exception 
and i get this exception only with this xml file 
thank you all for helping

Comment: My guess would be that your XML has a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8).

Comment: i didn't understant you well can you please be more specific

Comment: Did you read through the answers to the duplicate question?